# Error when emulating Titanium SDK application on Android: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-sdk

I see this error when emulating my application on Android

```
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [90,2129] Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication$1.uncaughtException(TiApplication.java:366)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreate(TiBaseActivity.java:769)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onCreate(TiActivity.java:47)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
```

titanium version 11.1.1 SDK